# how to count frequency in two array by ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Frequency of a string in an array of strings
Create a function you are given a collection of strings and a list of queries. For every query there is a string given. We need to print the number of times the given string occurs in the collection of strings.

Examples:

- Input :

  ```
  a[] = [wer, tyu, uio]
  b[] = [wer, wer, tyu, oio, tyu]
  ```
- Output : `[2 2 0]`

Explanation : 
`a[0]` appears two times in `b[]`

Comment: The naive approach would be `const output = a.map(astr=>b.filter(bstr=>bstr===astr).length);`

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli bad suggestion!

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: `a.map(s => b.reduce((a, c) => a + (s === c), 0))`

Comment: @Ele that is equally bad :)

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli not for sure, you're creating an additional array.

Comment: @Ele that is not a big issue, the real issue of both our suggestions is that we are doing multiple passes over the second array, when a single pass would suffice.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli assuming you're right, why did you suggest a bad approach?

Comment: Both approaches are not really bad. They are just not the most performant. On the other hand the OP hasn't shown any effort in trying to solve the problem, so i would not spend more time for it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function occur (a,b) {
 let count = [];

for (var i = 0; i<= a.length ; i++) {
 for (var j = 0;j<= b.length; j++) {
   if (a[i]==b[j]) { 
    
               return count[i] = count[i]++;
   }
  }
  
}
}
console.log(occur(["aaaa","cc" ,"dd"],["aaaa","dd"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use some form of hash to only iterate once through the collection of strings, before considering any of the queries. An ES6 `Map` can used for that purpose.

Then per entry in the hash you would have the frequency count (counted with `reduce`).

One idea would to not just return that hash, but return a function that consults the hash and returns the corresponding frequency or 0 if it is not in that hash.

Here is how that would look:

```js
// Returns function that can answer queries for the given collection of strings
function freq(strings) {
    const counts = strings.reduce((map, s) => map.set(s, (map.get(s)||0)+1), new Map);
    return s => counts.get(s) || 0;
}

// Sample call. The 3 queries are fed into the function returned by freq
const results = ["wer", "tyu", "uio"].map(freq(["wer", "wer", "tyu", "oio", "tyu"]));

console.log(results);
```